# Make a jframe appear only at the first start

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I have a program and I need to show a windows **only** at the first start of the application. What I should do?
I make two classes or two JFrames in one class?

Comment: Don't put multiple different components into the same class, always separate them, or your code will shortly become an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @BackSlash thanks. I thinked that, but how I effectively make a JFrame appear at the first start?

Comment: You have to keep track of that somehow. You could use a sqlite database as well as a simple txt file which holds a specific string if the application was started before

Comment: You are not talking about a startup screen? Often only a small rectangle with progress bar or such?

Comment: @BackSlash i thinked to use preferences but i don't know if it is correct

Comment: @JoopEggen yeah, something like that. More precisely a windows with some JTextField

Comment: Preferences are a good way to do it.  You can also create an empty file in the user’s cache directory after the first startup, but that directory varies by platform.

Comment: @VGR my idea was to set the start class of the jar on the first start Jframe class and before it appear to control if the application was previosly started or not, and if it was true to show the default jframe

Comment: There are special fast preloaded small windows one may customize. Or one could make ones own "login" window. The latter can be done as smaller dialog with a main JFrame parent.

Comment: @JoopEggen what special preloaded windows do you mean

Comment: [**Splash screen**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) was the name

Comment: I think I will use the solution of @BackSlash(you can write your comment as an answer if you want) because that is what I really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your goal is a **multiple document interface**.

- If the application is started a JFrame is opened with a new "document".
- If the application is started a second time the first JFrame appears instead.

Other scenarios:

- If a document is opened in the operating system, the application starts with that document (JDesktopWindow?) in a JFrame.
- If a second document is opened in the operating system, the first application opens the second document (in a new JDesktopWindow) in the same JFrame.

To implement this behaviour I used java **RMI** (remote method invocation).

- The application when running the first time listens on its chosen port as server.
- On start it tries as client to find a server (older instance of the application).
  If found it passes its command line arguments to an *open* call, and then quits.
- (Otherwise it starts the server and opens.)

Comment: where I can find a deepening?

Comment: Is that indeed what you wanted? Il y a beaucoup d'exemples sur RMI.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
   public class aaaaa {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new JFrame().setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

at the first you mean like this??

Comment: no, at the first start I mean at the **first start** of the **program**